# Why I can't import Snackbar class

Tags: android

I can't import this: `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;`

The result is: The import `android.support.design` cannot be resolved

Comment: Make sure you have added `dependencies` of design support library  `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+'`

Comment: Have you added design support dependency in _build.gradle_?

Comment: Post your build.gradle dependencies

Comment: @NileshRathod i think it's because of androidx

Comment: OK. I didn't add dependency

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the right library into your build.gradle.

If you are using the "normal" android library add this implementation:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

and this is the import statement:

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
```

---

If you are using the AndroidX library add this implementation:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

and this is the import statement:

```
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
```

Comment: you should probably include the import statements in your answer as well

Comment: Thanks.Are there other views that may require such implementation? For example I do not need that for Toast but for a Snacknar

Comment: It depends on what you need